# Wordpress: a 'Related Pages' or 'Associated Pages' plugin

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know of an existing **Related Pages** plugin for Wordpress, specifically where you can manually assign the 'related' pages yourself?

I may be searching for the wrong thing or using the wrong terminology, because everything I've found invariably relates to related *posts* or is based on tagging or an algorithm (for example [YARPP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/)), whereas what I require, ideally, is:

- You're editing a page, and there's an additional panel with a list of other pages;
- You check all the other pages that you want to associate with *this* page;
- Publish/Update the page, and the associations are saved accordingly.

If anybody is aware of something like this, then do let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This plugin supports both posts AND pages (regardless of what the plugin is actually called)

http://www.microkid.net/wordpress/related-posts/

You are able to select either page or post-type content to apply and relate to your other pages. It can also be widget-adapted to place almost anywhere on your page.

Comment: Dude, from having downloaded it and used it for all of 25 seconds, that is *exactly* what I was looking for. You've just saved me a couple of days of coding my own plugin. Thankyou!